# Why interval doesn't emit anything?

Tags: java, rx-java2

Why this code doesn't emit anything:

```
Observable<Long> observable1 = Observable.interval(3, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
observable1.subscribe(l -> System.out.println(l));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intervall()` operates on [`Scheduler.computation()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#computation--), which allocates a new thread. Your program terminates before the new thread has a chance to run. You can solve that by suspending  the main thread for a while.

```
Observable<Long> observable1 = Observable.interval(3, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
observable1.subscribe(l -> System.out.println(l));

try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
catch(InterruptedException e) { }
```

Now, you will see some output.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to know is that rx-java is asynchronus by nature.
It's difficult to say if you are aware of that judging just by this snippet.
If you just want to block and print it you shoud use blockingSubscribe in place of subscribe.